# In Java, does "==" Box or Unbox when comparing an object and a constant value?

Tags: java, reference, equals, comparison-operators

When comparing an Integer object and a constant value, does Java box the value or unbox the Integer object?

Based on what I have read, "==" is a reference comparison, therefore it's only logical to assume that Java boxes the constant to perform the reference comparison between the objects. Yet, the below test code seems to be give contradictory results.

```
Integer v1 = 1000;
Integer v2 = 1000;
boolean b1 = v1 == 1000; //True.
boolean b2 = v1 == v2; //False. Proof that 1000 boxes to new object and is not fetched from cache.
```

So how does object vs constant value comparison using `==` works in Java? Does the operator compare by value in this case?

Comment: using `Integer::valueOf(1000)` give you a chance of some caching.

Comment: IIRC, JLS requires for only 256 values to be cached by default i.e from -128 to 127. Also, `Integer v1 = 1000;` calls the `value0f` method internally.

Comment: It is guaranteed to cache -128 to 127 but may cache more. If you use `valueOf` it may cache, it may not - at least there is a chance!

Comment: I need not explicitly use the `valueOf` method. *Boxing internally calls that method*. `Integer v1 = 1000;` and `Integer v1 = Integer.valueOf(1000);` are the same, I know this from using the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call "a constant value" is an `int` literal, so its type is `int`.

[JLS 15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) says:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands.

In your `v1 == 1000` test, `1000` is of numeric type and `v1` is convertible to numeric type, so binary numeric promotion is performed.

[JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (Binary numeric promotion) says:

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion

Hence, the `Integer` operand - `v1` - is unboxed to an `int` and a comparison of two `int`s is performed. Therefore the result of the comparison is `true`.

When you compare two reference types - `v1 == v2` - no unboxing takes places, only the references are compared, as written in [JLS 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.

Since `1000` is too large to be cached by the `Integer` cache, `b1` and `b2` are not referencing the same instance, and therefore the result of the comparison is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Integer pools are same to string pool but it caches value if integer objects in the range **-128 to 127**
So when you try to assign a value in this **range** to a wrapper object, the **boxing** operation will invoke **Integer.valueOf** method and in turn it will **assign a reference to the object already** in the pool.

but, if you assign a value outside this **range** to a wrapper **reference** type, **Integer.valueOf** **will create a new Integer object** for that value. And hence, comparing the reference for Integer objects having value outside this range will give you false

So in your case

```
Integer v1 = 1000;
Integer v2 = 1000;
boolean b1 = v1 == 1000; //True.
boolean b2 = v1 == v2; // out of range so it will false but if you use 127 instead of 1000 then it will true.
```

check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)